# Problems forwarding a domain to an IP for RD Gateway

Tags: dns-hosting, godaddy, remote-desktop-gateway

I've been testing how to setup an RD Gateway for secure RDP. I've gone through the steps to give the server the proper roles, and I used a self signed certificate for the purpose of testing/learning. I was successfully able to RDP in with the public IP and the installed certificate.

My issue now is that I want to make it friendlier to setup and use the domain name to setup the RD Gateway settings. I want `remote.domainname.com` to be the RD gateway server name in the `settings`.

The domain is hosted by GoDaddy. I'm a bit lost in the control panel`settings`. Under "Forwarding", I can forward subdomains wherever I want, so in this case I forwarded `remote.domainname.com` to $Public_IP.

I tried both HTTP and HTTPS options, but when I put either as the RD Gateway server, it never connects and ends up timing out.

My guess is I'm doing the forwarding wrong and there's more to it in the DNS records than the control panel Forwarding page, but I can't find an answer.

Comment: Typically at this point you should use nslookup or dig to confirm that the name you have created and are connecting to exists in DNS.

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to forward the DNS name, but what you really need to do is create an A record for the name pointing to the public ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need a domain forwarder? I think you don't need one.

Perhaps just a simple A record will do the job.

Add A record `remote` pointing to IP.

From godaddy's [documentation](https://ie.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147):

```
Forwarding only
Redirects visitors to a destination URL of your choosing
Keeps the destination URL in the browser address bar
Example: Assign coolexample.com to forward only to coolwebsite.net. When a visitor types coolexample.com in a browser address bar, they will be redirected to the site for coolwebsite.net. The browser address bar will update to show coolwebsite.net.

Forwarding with masking
Redirects visitors to a destination URL of your choosing
Keeps your domain name in the browser address bar
Allows you to enter meta-tags for search engine information
Example: Assign coolexample.com to forward with masking to coolwebsite.net. When a visitor types coolexample.com in a browser address bar, they will be redirected to the site for coolwebsite.net. The browser address bar will continue to show coolexample.com, effectively masking the destination URL.
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need a new certificate with remote.domain.com
https://www.digitaldarragh.com/2022/07/11/updating-certificates-on-rds-remote-desktop-services/
And import it in rds. Please verify the certificate requirements what kind of certificate it needs to be

The Enhanced Key Usage extension has a value of either “Server Authentication” or “Remote Desktop Authentication” (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.54.1.2). You can also use certificates with no Enhanced Key Usage extension.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn781533(v=ws.11)